# Basic AES/CBC implementation in Java

Tags: java, aes

A little bit about myself: I am 18 years old, a student living in Germany and currently working on an android app.

I would like if someone has the time to review my code. I am especially interested **if this code has any vulnerabilities and if the efficiency could be improved**. Thanks in advance :)

```
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.spec.*;
import java.util.Base64;

public class AES {

    public static int iterations = 1000;
    private static String seperator = ";";
    private static int key_length = 256;
    private static int salt_length = 64;

    private static final String HASH_ALGORITHM = "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256";
    private static final String KEY_ALGORITHM = "AES";
    private static final String CIPHER_ALGORITHM = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";

    public static void setSaltLength(int length) throws Exception {
        if((length > 0) && ((length & (length - 1)) == 0))
            salt_length = length;
        else
            throw new Exception("Invalid Salt Length");

    }

    public static void setKeyLength(int length) throws Exception {
        if(length == 128 || length == 192 || length == 256)
            key_length = length;
        else
            throw new Exception("Invalid Length");
    }

    public static void setSeperator(String s) throws Exception {
        if(seperator.matches("[^+=/\\w]"))
            seperator = s;
        else
            throw new Exception("Invalid Seperator");
    }

    public static void setDurationOnCurrentComputer(int milliseconds){
        char[] password = {'t', 'e', 's', 't'};
        int i = 1;
        long duration = 0;
        while(duration < milliseconds) {
            i*=2;
            long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
            byte[] salt = new byte[64];
            new SecureRandom().nextBytes(salt);
            try {
                createKey(password, salt, i);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - t;
            System.out.println("i: " + i + " duration: " + duration);
        }
        iterations = i;
    }

    private static SecretKey createKey(char[] password, byte[] salt, int iterations) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(HASH_ALGORITHM);
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, iterations, key_length);
        SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        return new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), KEY_ALGORITHM);
    }

    public static String encrypt(char[] password, byte[] data) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidParameterSpecException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_ALGORITHM);
        byte[] salt = new byte[salt_length];
        new SecureRandom().nextBytes(salt);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, createKey(password, salt, iterations));
        AlgorithmParameters params = cipher.getParameters();
        byte[] iv = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
        byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(data);
        Base64.Encoder e = Base64.getEncoder();
        return e.encodeToString((e.encodeToString(iv) + seperator + e.encodeToString(ciphertext) + seperator + e.encodeToString(salt)).getBytes());
    }

    public static String decrypt(char[] password, String ciphertext) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        Base64.Decoder d = Base64.getDecoder();
        String[] data = new String(d.decode(ciphertext)).split(seperator);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_ALGORITHM);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, createKey(password, d.decode(data[2]), iterations), new IvParameterSpec(d.decode(data[0])));
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(d.decode(data[1])));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>     public static int iterations = 1000;
> ```

That seems quite low. See e.g. [1](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/10335/1127), [2](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/3993/20403). Or is the idea that you will use `setDurationOnCurrentComputer` always?

---

> ```
>     private static String seperator = ";";
> ```

Please correct the spelling to *separator* throughout the code.

---

> ```
>     private static int key_length = 256;
>     private static int salt_length = 64;
> ```

`static`? I find that surprising.

---

> ```
>     private static final String CIPHER_ALGORITHM = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
> ```

Is there any good reason to choose CBC over GCM? The latter is more parallelisable, and I'm using it on Android API 19, which could fairly be described as ancient.

---

> ```
>     public static void setSaltLength(int length) throws Exception {
>         if((length > 0) && ((length & (length - 1)) == 0))
>             salt_length = length;
>         else
>             throw new Exception("Invalid Salt Length");
>
>     }
> ```

I think this method could use a few improvements:

1. Why a checked exception? `IllegalArgumentException` looks like the natural fit here.
2. Why must the salt length be a power of 2? That requirement is non-obvious, so it should be documented, and it wouldn't be a bad idea to also comment the test.
3. The person who catches that exception will have rude words for the person who wrote the message. `"Invalid Salt Length: " + length` is *much* more useful for debugging.

---

> ```
>     public static String encrypt(char[] password, byte[] data) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidParameterSpecException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidKeySpecException {
> ```

I think you could reasonably throw `GeneralSecurityException` and simplify that signature a bit.

---

> ```
>         byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(data);
> ```

While this is tempting, I can tell you from personal experience that it may fail for large data blocks in some API levels. I can't remember offhand whether it was 64kB or 128kB which was the upper limit; to play it safe I suggest calling `update` with 16kB chunks.

---

> ```
>         Base64.Encoder e = Base64.getEncoder();
>         return e.encodeToString((e.encodeToString(iv) + seperator + e.encodeToString(ciphertext) + seperator + e.encodeToString(salt)).getBytes());
>     }
> ```

Ok, that's not efficient. Base64 encoding adds an overhead of 33%. Do it twice and you have an overhead of 78%. Ditch the outer `encodeToString`.

Also, there are two problems with the contents. Putting `salt` at the end means that you can't start decrypting until you've read the entire string, which is a problem for stream-based operation. And failing to include the value of `iterations` in the string could mean that you aren't able to decrypt it later.

---

The hardest part of cryptography is key management. There are some clues that you intend this to be used only locally: i.e. you won't be transmitting the ciphertext to another computer to decipher it remotely. So I would strongly suggest that you look at [KeyStore](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html).

Answer (score 0):

I am far to be a crypto expert but I do not see anything wrong.

However you should use the naming conventions for your fields. You can also consider to create an instance of your `AES` object or a via *factory* if you want to control the instance(s). This will remove all the `static` methods that can cause troubles in a concurrent environment.